# "Shaky" CSS3 transition with IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've been working on a very simple effect: a slow zoom effect on hovering on a image, using CSS3 transition. It renders nice and smothly on every broswer I had the chance to test it (Mozzila, Chrome, Safari), but it is shaky when I use IE 11.

Here's the code:

html

```
<div class="container">
<img />
</div>
```

css

```
.container {
width:310px;
height:220px;    
overflow:hidden;
}

img {
width:100%;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.zoom {
-webkit-transform: scale(1.06); 
-moz-transform: scale(1.06);
-o-transform: scale(1.06);
transform: scale(1.06);
}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.container').hover(function() {

        $('img',this).addClass('zoom');

        }, function() {
        $('img',this).removeClass('zoom');
        });
    });
```

You can find the demo here:

https://jsfiddle.net/malambart/Leydw2tp/1/

If someone had a idea of how to fix this, I'll be glad to try it. However I'll be happy just to remove the animation for any version of IE. Sorry to ask something that may be obvious to many people but what is the best way to acheive that? I just learned about a library called Modernizr but as I understand it only tell me if a feature is available, not allow me to "turn off" features on some browsers. Am I wrong?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change your transforms:

```
scale(1.06);
```

Into:

```
rotate(0.1deg)scale(1.06)
```